# Touchpad unresponsive after few second on MacBook Pro 9,2 [Ubuntu Focal Fossa 20.04]

Tags: touchpad, 20.04, mac, macbook-pro, apple

On a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04 Fossal Focal on Apple MacBook Pro 9,2, the touchpad often becomes unresponsive after few second. I becomes unresponsive after 1 to 3s if I drag and drop, after bout 5s when two fingers scrolling, and for regular one finger touch, it appears more random.

I don't remember having this issue on previous releases, but It's been a while I haven't done a fresh install. I made an install of 12.04 in 2013 and then successfully upgrade to the different LTS (14.04, 16.04 and 18.04).

Here the output of `xinput`

```
$ xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ bcm5974                                   id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in):            id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Apple Computer, Inc. IR Receiver          id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Apple Inc. Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Bellow the list of properties corresponding to the touchpad

```
$ xinput list-props 13
Device 'bcm5974':
    Device Enabled (164):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (166): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Tapping Enabled (302): 0
    libinput Tapping Enabled Default (303): 0
    libinput Tapping Drag Enabled (304):    1
    libinput Tapping Drag Enabled Default (305):    1
    libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled (306):   0
    libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled Default (307):   0
    libinput Tapping Button Mapping Enabled (308):  1, 0
    libinput Tapping Button Mapping Default (309):  1, 0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (310):   1
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (311):   0
    libinput Disable While Typing Enabled (312):    1
    libinput Disable While Typing Enabled Default (313):    1
    libinput Scroll Methods Available (314):    1, 1, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled (315):   1, 0, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (316):   1, 0, 0
    libinput Click Methods Available (317): 1, 1
    libinput Click Method Enabled (318):    0, 1
    libinput Click Method Enabled Default (319):    0, 1
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled (320):    0
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled Default (321):    0
    libinput Accel Speed (322): 0.000000
    libinput Accel Speed Default (323): 0.000000
    libinput Left Handed Enabled (324): 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (325): 0
    libinput Send Events Modes Available (287): 1, 1
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (288):    0, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (289):    0, 0
    Device Node (290):  "/dev/input/event9"
    Device Product ID (291):    1452, 595
    libinput Drag Lock Buttons (326):   <no items>
    libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (327):   1
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `xinput` terminal command.

Comment: I edited my post

Comment: Now please add output of `xinput list-props 13`

Comment: I added the list of xinput properties for the touchpad

Comment: All looks good to me. It may be some kernel regression.